# Generalized bilinear estimates

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Hello. Let $ X^{s,b} $ be the Bourgain space generated by $ \tau - \xi^3 $. It is proved that, for $ s\in (-\frac{1}{2}, 0] $, we have

$$
 \|(u^2)_x\| _{X^{s,b'-1}} \leq c \|u\|_{X^{s,b}} \|u\|_{X^{-\frac{1}{2},b}} 
$$

for some $ b, b' \in (\frac{1}{2},1) $, see JDE 2002 (185) 25-53.

I want to know whether it holds that

$$
\|(uv)_x\|_{X^{s,b'-1}} \leq c\|u\|_{X^{s,b}} \|v\|_{X^{-\epsilon,b}}
$$

for some $ \epsilon>0 $. Some references which include similar results are welcome.

Comment: I cleaned up the LaTeX for you

Comment: The JDE paper being referenced can be found at http://www.labma.ufrj.br/~rrosa/publications.html or directly at http://www.labma.ufrj.br/~rrosa/dvifiles/kdvl2.pdf

Comment: Why do you expect the product uv to be as smooth as u?